# Avoiding implicit conversions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I am working on a project that needs to have a generic C++ wrapper for big number libraries and, if the library provides C-style functions like so:

```
//assignment
lib_set(lib_type data, lib_type input);
lib_set_si(lib_type data, long input);
lib_set_ui(lib_type data, unsigned long input);

//addition
lib_add(lib_type data, lib_type input);
lib_add_ui(lib_type data, unsigned long input);
```

In order to avoid creating temporary objects when it's not really necessary, I ended up with something like this:

```
class wrapper
{
private:
    lib_type data;
public:

    wrapper()
    {
        lib_set_ui(this->data, 0UL);
    }

    wrapper (const wrapper &input)
    {
        lib_set(this->data, input.data);
    }

    wrapper (const long input)
    {
        lib_set_si(this->data, input);
    }

    wrapper (const unsigned long input)
    {
        lib_set_ui(this->data, input);
    }

    wrapper &operator+= (const wrapper &input)
    {
        lib_add(this->data, input.data);
        return *this;
    }

    wrapper &operator+= (const unsigned long input)
    {
        lib_add_ui(this->data, input);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, if I do this:

```
wrapper x(2);
x += -2;
```

the compiler (GCC / VS2010) won't even issue a warning that I'm trying to cast an `int` to `unsigned long` implicitly, and it's definitely not what I want to get...

So, in this case, how would I overload operators for the `wrapper` class, such that I don't need to create a temporary `wrapper` object when it's not needed? If I remove the `wrapper &operator+= (const unsigned long input)` overload, then I would have to use something like this:

```
wrapper x(2);
x += wrapper(-2);
x += -2;//implicitly casts -2 to wrapper
```

but I don't think I can rely on the fact that the compiler might be able to optimize away the extra object...

Comment: I'd presume you're calling the `const long` parametred-version with both of those. There might be no conversion even going on.

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: Oh, now I read this properly. Edit: Oh god I just should stop answering questions I'm mixing up answers and comments

Comment: If you provide an overload for a signed int += does it work correctly?

Comment: @Jay That is one way of solving it, but then I would have to provide one for `unsigned int`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, won't I? I was hoping to avoid that... If I can't avoid it, then which would be the ones that I must implement in order to avoid these kind of issues?

Comment: @MihaiTodor Just the largest types (such as `int64_t`/`uint64_t`) or the largest types you require for your data.

Comment: The code in the question seems wrong, as `wrapper::data` is read from but never assigned.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, it's kind of silly, but lib_type is actually some pointer wrapped up in a #define, so, I can pass it safely to `lib_set_ui`, which also initializes it, but anyway, let's ignore this for now. Here's some mockup code that doesn't give any warnings, even if compiled with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c++0x -O2 -static test.cpp -o test`, GCC v4.7.2: https://ideone.com/OUJahd

Comment: @MooingDuck: I'm guessing the C library does something tricky like `typedef struct Something lib_type[1];` so what looks like pass-by-value is effectively by reference.

Comment: @aschepler: I've never heard of such a thing, but that's quite clever.  Does that actually work?

Comment: GCC 4.3.4 _errors_ on this code: http://ideone.com/z18deo  Are you certain it didn't even warn for you?  MSVC should also have the same error.  If [I change the first `2` to `2l`](http://ideone.com/v17qZX) I get the results you describe.

Comment: It looks like you sometimes have `test` where you mean `wrapper`.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I renamed `class test` into `class wrapper`, for clarity. I think I replaced all references now...

Comment: @AndreiTita So, if I also implement `wrapper &operator+= (const long input)` (by forwarding it to `wrapper &operator-= (const unsigned long abs_input)` in case of negatives), then I should be safe? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @MihaiTodor Well, it's a bit complicated because of promotion rules. You will be safe, but depending on the types involved, you might get overload ambiguities (compiler error) which will require some explicit casting, which may or may not be acceptable in your case.

Comment: @AndreiTita I find it acceptable to use explicit casts when it's required, rather than to pull my hair out from a silent underflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to disable the implicit conversion as you describe. However, you can at least make the compiler issue a warning on it.

If you're using gnu Mingw/gcc just pass `-Wconversion` and `-Wsign-conversion` when compiling. You should be getting a warning now on your above code.

For MSVC, `/Wall` or `/W4` should get you the same thing.

Comment: +1 for `-Wsign-conversion`. I was almost sure that it's enabled by either `-Wall` or `-Wextra`. Do you know any other such cute warning switch that I should send to the compiler besides `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion` to play safe? Is there any way to achieve the same thing in Visual Studio?

Comment: @MihaiTodor: Visual Studio warns about sign conversions by default I thought.  if not, go into the project settings, and somewhere in there you can set the warning level to a higher level.  (3 is default I think)

Comment: @MooingDuck It seems I have to go to `/W4`, but thanks for pointing this out! It really helps.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, that explains a lot - I forgot to enable /W4 on the project where I test random code.